# Dependant taxonomy fields for new nodes not written to database

Tags: drupal-7

I have a content type that that has several dependent fields and several taxonomies as fields. Two of the taxonomies are not being written to the database all of a sudden. These fields are conditional based on the value of the another taxonomy field. The dependent taxonomy fields are not written to the relevant `field_data_field_[taxonomy_name]` table in the database; that is, there is no line in the table linked to the node. The other depended fields and other taxonomy fields in the content type work fine. This seems to be related to the combination of taxonomy and dependent.

No relevant errors are showing in dblog.

This used to work a couple months ago and I've tried retracing my steps from changes that I've made over that time but I can't find the cause of the problem. I haven't touched the field dependencies settings, which for these two problem fields are:

Condition: Value
Values input mode: Insert value from widget... (with the appropriate taxonomy term selected from the dependee field)

Drupal 7.34
Conditional Fields 7.x-3.0-alpha1

Have any of you encountered a problem like this? Where should I look next?

Comment: Changing the dependency value from "select from widget" to "regular expression" seems to resolve the problem. Sounds like a bug, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the dependency value from "select from widget" to "regular expression" seems to resolve the problem.